# Can we say positive verbs + neither?

Tags: grammar, neither-nor, either-any

I ask my question by the following example:

> A: Would you like tea or coffee? B: I don't want either.

Can we say the following instead of the above one?:

> A: Would you like tea or coffee? B: I **want neither**.

In the grammar book isn't mentioned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say it, but I don't think it's very common in that context, perhaps because if you're refusing something you do usually want to use a negative verb.

In general, I find *neither* in subject position pretty normal, but in other positions it's a little bit stilted, compared to *either* and a negative verb.

> Neither he nor his brother wanted to be involved.
>
> I saw neither the manager nor her assistant

(object position - a little bit stilted compared to:)

> I didn't see either the manager or her assistant.